# issue with adding rows in a table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

So I'm trying to add rows in a table based on a specific table with its columns but I don't know why I'm not getting what I want to get

Here is what I did:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount(); 
for(int i = 1; i<=columnsNumber; i++)
{
System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ": ");
row = kb.next();
sql = "INSERT INTO "+TableName+ "("+rsmd.getColumnName(i)+") VALUES ('"+row+"')";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
System.out.println();
```

However, when I list the table (after adding values for the first time) I get:

```
Table Name
=========================================
Col 1               Col 2               
                    name               
1234                null
```

The SQL result for what I have is:

```
INSERT INTO Tablename(Col 1) VALUES ('1234')
INSERT INTO Tablename(Col 2) VALUES ('name')
```

I don't know why it's doing this, what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
Table Name
=========================================
Col 1               Col 2               
1234                name
```

BTW: Col 1 is the primary key
that's the first time,

when I try to add any other values, I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

To sum up what I want to accomplish: I'm trying to add an entry for each column in the same row
so I want to start from column 1 and add row 1, then go to column 2 and add a value to row 1 as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what `kb` is.

Comment: Try printing the `sql` and you might see the issue.  You're inserting separate rows per column, instead of building the sql to insert a single row...  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  You are selecting from a table and inserting back into the same one?

Comment: @sgeddes I am trying to inset a single row at a time in a table for each column. A sample result would be what I have in the question

Comment: Am I missing something?  Isn't the problem simply that you are inserting something which already exists, violating the primary key constraint?

Comment: @Brandon No, I get the message even if I'm inserting something new

Comment: This sounds like confusion over the term `insert`.  You are trying to set the value of a column for an existing row.  `insert` creates a new row.

Comment: The error message is because you are not specifying value for the column that has the unique index, and it looks to be defaulting to the empty string '' when not specified;

Comment: @JRD I'm not sure what do you mean by the "unique index", could you clarify that please?

Comment: See [CREATE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html), A unique index enforces a column's value only appears once across all rows.

Comment: @JRD is the unique index the same as the primary key then? if yes, then I've actually specified a primary key when I created the table ( it is col 1 in this case)

Comment: A unique index is technically different from a primary key, but the results are the same.  For purposes of this discussion, yes, we can say they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting 2 rows, and only setting 1 column at a time. Looks like you may want an insert statement that looks more like:

```
insert into Tablename(column 1, column 2, etc...) values (column 1 value, column 2 value, ...);
```

If you still want to generate the SQL statement dynamically, then you'll want to build the statement, then only execute it once (outside of the loop).

Also, it looks like you have a unique index that is preventing the empty string from being inserted.

Comment: I would like to make the user know what exactly is he adding and to which column, that's why I'm doing what I'm doing. I would like to add multiple columns to the same row while making the user aware of it.

Comment: You'll need to use an UPDATE statement then after the 1st insert.

Comment: Well, the thing is, the first insert is inserting in the second row for some reason and not the first row !

Comment: That is exactly what INSERT is designed to do. INSERT will only ever insert a new row. If you want to modify columns in an existing row, you'll need to use an UPDATE statement.

Comment: but you said that I'll need to use an update after the 1st insert. If the 1st insert is not doing what it's supposed to do then how exactly can I do what I want? Can I use UPDATE without using INSERT? (since the columns are already there)

Comment: Can you post the results from `DESC TableName` and `SHOW INDEX FROM TableName`?

Comment: I didn't get any answer for :       sql = " DESC TableName";
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
     sql = " SHOW INDEX FROM TableName";
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` is used to create a new row in a table.  Let's step through your code for each iteration.

Table schema

```
TestTable
ColA  ||  ColB || ColC || ColD
------------------------------
```

Code:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=columnsNumber; i++)
{
    System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ": ");
    row = kb.next();
    sql = "INSERT INTO "+TableName+ "("+rsmd.getColumnName(i)+") VALUES ('"+row+"')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

First iteration, you run this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (ColA) VALUES ("first value");
```

Now your table looks like

```
TestTable
ColA        || ColB || ColC || ColD
-----------------------------------
first value || null || null | null
```

Run the code again

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (ColB) VALUES ("second value");

TestTable
ColA        || ColB         || ColC || ColD
-------------------------------------------
first value || null         || null || null
null        || second value || null || null
```

One more iteration.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (ColC) VALUES ("third value");

TestTable
ColA        || ColB         || ColC        || ColD
--------------------------------------------------
first value || null         || null        || null
null        || second value || null        || null
null        || null         || third value || null
```

Now, if you have a `primary key` or `unique` constraint on `ColA`, what would happen when trying to insert that third row?  That's where your constraint violation is coming from.

I can't offer a solution because I don't understand what you are trying to do.  This entire model seems upside down.  You are treating rows as columns and columns as rows.  Columns are the fixed structure that every row must adhere to.  Rows are the dynamic set of entries that you insert, update, or delete.

If you are trying to update the values of each column of a given row, then you need a SQL `UPDATE` statement rather than `INSERT`, but you also need to identify the row.  You're not identifying any specific rows in your code, so it's not clear which row you should update.

This sounds like an XY problem.  You have problem X, think Y is the solution, and are asking for help in doing Y.  But if we understood X, we could offer a different solution.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, now I understand why what I have is doing what it's doing, but I am still not sure how to accomplish what I want. The current code will print to the user(I'm going to use your db): ColA: (the user will provide an entry) then ColB: (the user's entry) then ColC: (the user's entry) finally, ColD: (the user entry). I'm trying to have: first value, second value, third value, and fourth all in the same row (one in each column (colA,colB,colC and ColD))

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention in my previous comment that my code is not putting "first value" in the first row, it's putting it in the second row instead

Comment: That makes sense.  If the PK is on the first column and you start populating at the second column, then your second insert would fail because they would both have `null` for the PK value.  You would get an error on the second `insert`, which is exactly what happened.

Comment: I actually started populating the first column first but that didn't work, so I'm not sure why is this a problem, and how exactly can I accomplish what I want?